# apache httpd virtual hosts setup keep hitting the same VirtualHost

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to set up two virtual hosts. Here's my httpd config:

```
<Directory /Users/userX/dev/sandbox-2>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from All
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/userX/dev/sandbox-2"
    ServerName blah                                                        
</VirtualHost>                     

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/userX/dev/sandbox"
    ServerName fooboar
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that, no matter which server name I try to access in my browser (blah or foobar) it'll serve from blah's DocumentRoot. However, if I were to comment out the the VirtualHost for blah, then it'll take me to foobar's DocumentRoot.

Comment: I haven't seen vhosts done that way, could you try changing the three instances of `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.1:80` to make sure it matches?

Comment: Thanks. You're right but there were actually multiple mistakes with my config. Solution posted at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues..

The biggest one is that I had a typo. (I had fooboar, not foobar)

Second, I need to include the port in NameVirtualHost as well as in

Also, what helped a lot while debugging this was start httpd in debug mode which is:

```
apachectl -e debug
```